# Can I get all the information I need to create a payment transaction from BlockExplorer?

Tags: transactions

Let's say I have a bitcoin address that I want to make a payment from.

I understand that to create a payment from that address I need to get the unspent outs. Can I get that information from BlockExplorer ?

And if so to create the payment do I just need the transaction hash of the transaction containing the out and the index of the out ?

**Update : **

You can assume I have the private key. So what I'm looking for is a list of unspent outs by public key.

I can see how to retrieve transactions for an address i.e. http://blockexplorer.com/q/mytransactions/1JjvT5HoVoqhyLN2cb9imMsN9HgYAK268m

**Update 2 : **

I should have mentioned that I want to do this programmitcally, i.e. through the BlockExplorer query API. http://blockexplorer.com/q

Answer (score 5):

To create a payment, you need a private key with an associated public key that has funds, a public key of the recipient, have the hash of the last transaction made on your public key, and perform some hashing on all of those.

Block explorer provides all the information but the private key. If you have that, you can generate a valid transaction on your own.

Comment: OK, but how do I get that information from BlockExplorer ?

Comment: Search for your address, find your last transaction, get its hash. You should know all of the addresses, put it all together. For example, transaction: http://blockexplorer.com/address/1JjvT5HoVoqhyLN2cb9imMsN9HgYAK268m has hash c29839e577d3cb6b3703d28b9027ddf23ed428d3 .

Comment: I should have mentioned I wanted to use the BlockExplorer API. i.e. http://blockexplorer.com/q/mytransactions/1PurtonoEouSwXZXZqddxWgeLTRJynr51A, for yur address I get http://blockexplorer.com/q/mytransactions/1JjvT5HoVoqhyLN2cb9imMsN9HgYAK268m